Find side length of quadrilateral with two right angles given two adjacent sides and a third angle.
How is it possible to calculate a particular side length of a quadrilateral with two right angles, given two adjacent sides and a third angle. In the example picture I know sides a and b, as well as angle alpha, and I need to calculate side c.
Much appreciated!
quadrilateral with two right angles, and two sides and one additional angle are given

Welcome to the site. You should show what you have tried for solving this problem.

Have you tried to connect the two right angles with a line segment ?

I would connect the vertices of the right angles in your image and use the cosine rule to find the length of this diagonal (as $a,b$ and $\alpha$ are given), then after finding an angle, you can use the cosine rule for the smaller triangle and find the other side.

Thanks! I had completely forgotten about the cosine rule!

Calculate as you draw it:
$$A=(0,0) \to B=(0,b) \to C = B + a \ (\cos \alpha,\sin \alpha)$ \to D= C + c \ (\cos (\alpha+\pi/2,\sin \alpha+\pi/2\to (0,0).$$
The closing side has length
$$|d|=\sqrt{(A-C)^2}$$
The angles on the inner sides are complementary angles of the  direction angles, positive sense, zero direction angle points east/right.
